# Null pointer in putExtras

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have some trouble with putExtras to an intent. Could you please review my code?

```
 public void onSelectCategory(View v) {
    int category = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("EXT_CATEGORY", category);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in the ListActivity, I'm doing the following..

```
public static final String EXT_CATEGORY = "category";
int category = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(EXT_CATEGORY);
```

Comment: pls check @Deepanker Chaudhary answer and remove "folllowed the help in SO yet no luck" from headinng :)

Comment: @vnshetty: Done, you also have sufficient reputation to clean this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Sahil yeah but i just wanted LilYoda to verify the answer and try to implement it... anyway thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this line

```
         intent.putExtra("EXT_CATEGORY", category);
```

in your another activity String name should be same means:--

```
         public static final String EXT_CATEGORY = "EXT_CATEGORY";
```

Comment: Along with you're answer I also did this and it worked.          `String category = (String) v.getTag();`

Answer (score 1):

You did several mistakes, here is a overworker version of your code.

```
 public void onSelectCategory(View v) {
    int category = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXT_CATEGORY, category);
    startActivity(intent);
}

int defaultCat = -1;
public static final String EXT_CATEGORY = "category";
int category = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXT_CATEGORY,defaultCat); // Use default int if there is no extra
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to get you info, not `getExtras()` :

```
int category = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXT_CATEGORY");
```

`getExtras()` returns additional `Bundle` of data. You need only one integer.